# При запуске программы выдает ошибку "Индекс за пределы ..."

Tags: c#

вот собственно как выглядит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот собственно сам код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string project_name;

        public static string Project_name
        {
            set { project_name = value; }
            get { return project_name; }
        }

        [STAThreadAttribute]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string skan_directory = string.Empty;      // директория для сканирования

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

            string project_path = args[0] ?? "";
            project_name = args[1] ?? "<< PROJECT NAME >>";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(project_path))
            {
                SkanFiles(project_path, @"*.txt");
                SkanFiles(project_path, @"*.cpp");
                SkanFiles(project_path, @"*.s");
                SkanFiles(project_path, @"*.h");
            }
        }

        private static void SkanFiles(string dir, string mask)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(dir, mask, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string file_patch in dirs)
                {
                    FileInfo files = new FileInfo(file_patch);
                    if (File.Exists(file_patch))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader sfile = new StreamReader(file_patch))
                        {
                            string str;
                            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str = sfile.ReadLine()))
                            {
                                str.Replace(" << PROJECT NAME >> ", Project_name);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("\t-->{0,-20}\t({1} кБайт)", 
                        files.Name, files.Length / 1024);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void SetFontColor(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

выдается ошибка тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немогу понять

Comment: Научитесь дебажить или пишите в блокноте, раз все равно не используете возможности IDE. А что непонятного, собственно? Вам все написано: в массиве нет такого индекса. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к 0-му индексу пустого массива, вот Вам и ошибка. Потом Вы добавили проверку на то, есть ли в массиве 2 элемента. Ошибок больше нет, но массив-то по-прежнему пуст, так что код внутри блока проверки попросту не выполняется

Comment: в самом коде нет проверки на 2 . я сам просто попытался

Comment: Параметр `args` в Main заполняется аргументами командной строки при запуске

Comment: какие значения индекса следует мне вводить?

Comment: Вы в курсе, что такое аргументы командной строки?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89816/discussion-between-jamaka-and-kir-antipov).